# Exporting from Blender 2.8 to LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, blender, fbx

i used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398669/rendered-3d-object-using-libgdx-does-not-have-colors-as-used-to-create-using-ble) code to render an object created in Blender 2.8.
But my object is not rendering. I also tried to use the [libgdx-fbxconv-gui](https://github.com/ASneakyFox/libgdx-fbxconv-gui) to convert my fbx file to an g3db file. In the libgdx-fbxconv-gui software my model is rendering like it should be. Do you have any suggestions? I also tried some other models which i found in the g3db format. They are showing properly with the same code.

Answer (score 3):

So I found out that blender sets the opacity in the materials to 0.
You can change it back with this code:

```
Model model = modelLoader.loadModel(Gdx.files.getFileHandle(path, Files.FileType.Internal));
    for (Material m : model.materials) {
        m.set(new BlendingAttribute(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA));
    }
```